# Panel control stuck on visible=false

Tags: vb.net, panel

Im using vb2008 express edition.
I have a form with panel control set to visible=false( i add it for copy it properties).
I tried to add panels dynamically but when i do it, i cant see it on the form.
I even set code line for panel.visble=true but when i run the watch window it stuck on visible =false

```
Sub addPlayer(ByVal p As Form2.player)
        '  Timer1.Enabled = False
        Dim gap As Integer = 20
        Dim pan123 As New Panel
        Dim nick As New Label, colorFrame As New Label

        pan123.Size = New Size(100, 100)
        pan123.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
        pan123.ForeColor = Color.Aquamarine
        pan123.Location = New Point(200, 200)
        'pan.Size = Panel1.Size
        'pan.Location = Panel1.Location
        'pan.Top = Panel1.Top + Panel1.Height * playersNum + gap * playersNum


        nick.Text = p.nick
        nick.Size = Label2.Size
        nick.Location = Label2.Location
        nick.Font = Label2.Font
        nick.AutoSize = True


        colorFrame.AutoSize = False
        colorFrame.Size = Label3.Size
        colorFrame.Location = Label3.Location
        colorFrame.BackColor = p.colorP

        pan123.Visible = True
        'pan.Controls.Add(nick)
        'pan.Controls.Add(colorFrame)
        Me.Controls.Add(pan123)


        'nick.Visible = True

        playersNum = playersNum + 1
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Me` here? Why do you have `ByVal p As Form2.player` as parameter? Don't use default instances of Forms. You're missing `pan123.BringToFront()` and the Label controls are not added to any container. You don't need a hidden Panel, you need a FlowLayoutPanel as container for your Panels. -- [Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is free software.

Comment: @Jimi me is the form that i want to add . p is a structure of player that i build. i turn off the labels to see if its help. the problem that is stay on false status even when i pass it in the watch window where i declare pan123=false. it look like a system bug

Comment: *What is `Me` here?* is asking what **instance** of what Form class is `Me` referring to. Do you know what `BringToFront()` and a FlowLayoutPanel are used for? -- Remove `ByVal p As Form2.player` from that method and pass a *real* argument: a real instance of `player` or the corresponding property values that the method needs.

Comment: hi @Jimi . ok the problem was with a thread that i have in the program and cuase to a conflict. i used invoke function to solve it. 10x.